# Run npm project cloned from git

Tags: reactjs, npm

I want to run npm project, which was cloned from git, on my computer, but usual command like `npm start` did not work. Can someone give some tutorial how to start such projects or share some information.

Comment: can you elaborate more on what project you've cloned, or the contents of packages.json file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check the readme.md of the git repo for instructions.

But from experience, the cloned project should have a package.json.
In terminal at the root of the project run `npm install` to install necessary dependencies. 
Then check if `npm start` is set up properly inside the 'Scripts' object in your package.json
Finally run `npm start`
This should do it for you, but most attention should paid to instructions inside `README.md` provided by  developer.

Answer (score -1):

Inside package.json
edit "start" to this code:
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",